# Java Play Framework 2.6 does not return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` CORS header

Tags: java, playframework, cors, playback

Play does not honor my `application.conf` configuration to return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. When I send a request from Ajax, the response is always:

`Failed to load http://localhost:9000/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

This is what my `application.conf` looks like:

```
# disable the built in filters
play.http.filters = play.api.http.NoHttpFilters

play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"

play.filters {
    cors {
    # The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
    allowedOrigins = null
   }
}
```

The only way I have succeeded in getting the Ajax request through, is by adding the line `response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in the controller. But I want to do it through `application.conf` so I don't have to add this `setHeader()` code in all the controllers.

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        // this is the only hack that works
        //response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        return ok(
            Json.toJson("A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....")
        );
    }
}
```

My Ajax request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9000",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(_out) {
        alert(_out);
    },
    fail: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Why is Play not honoring my `application.conf` configuration for CORS?

Answer (score 1):

I have determined the problem. In my `application.conf`:

```
play.http.filters = play.api.http.NoHttpFilters

play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
```

These two lines are not additive. In other words, the first line disables all filters and the second line enables a filter, but the end result is still that all filters are disabled (even though ENabling comes AFTER DIsabling).